# How do I properly edit Twitter Bootstrap 2.0 with my rails app -Images overlapping & making jQuery Masonry work with it

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap

Just wanted to add, this is on my local development machine & have been building a small social network more for fun & learning purposes.

I've searched & played around with this for awhile -I got the thumbnails working side by side by playing around with code on Jsfiddle, but have since lost the tab.

I've uploaded an image -

[image]

Have set up so users have galleries by uploading images (carrierwave) & the little boxes are on the bottom are off as well.
Can anyone help me -currently, using;

Bootstrap Rails 
https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails
&
Bootstrap Sass

Also, wanting to add jQuery Masonry in there -but it hasn't really been working at all.

Comment: We need more information about your problem.

Comment: Okay, how do I properly make a 3 column thumbnail grid on a fixed layout, using carrierwave -so that users can upload images & with enough padding that the images are stacked side by side & will continue filling out the page in a row of 3 thumbnails when a user uploads a file (image).

Comment: Right now have it using how Ryan Bates had galleries & paintings -I was thinking, is it possible to make a thumbnail class or set up the css/html properly to have user upload image & then image gets added to image -but then would need to have thumbnails & images generated at the same time upon form submission.  If it helps, this is very similar to a tumblr theme.  Thank You, please tell me if you need any more information.

Answer (score 0):

Use the settings in masonry options:

```
columnWidth : 270,
gutterWidth: 30
```